# Can't open GetBundles when clicking it in the Bundles menu in TextMate

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles, bundles

I can install the GetBundles bundle, but when I click on it (Bundles > GetBundles > GetBundles), nothing happens.

I've followed multiple guides, and they all lead me to the same situation.  Here's an example of one such guide:

http://solutions.treypiepmeier.com/2009/02/25/installing-getbundles-on-a-fresh-copy-of-textmate/

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Ruby 1.9? It seems GetBundles doesn't work with Ruby 1.9

You can check its log file (Bundles > GetBundles > Open Log File), might see some syntax errors there.

Comment: I was using rvm, but I can't recall which version it was now.  I've long since made the switch to Vim, but thanks for the reply.